# Openfire Plugin: Null Pointer Exception when trying to get the instance of the plugin

Tags: plugins, openfire

I'm developing a plugin for openfire.

From the jsp, I'm using getters and setters to transfer data.
My problem is similar to the problem mentioned here:
https://community.igniterealtime.org/message/155892#155892

I have been trying to figure it out from a week.

I have the following code:

```
<%@ page
   import="org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer,
           de.meisterfuu.openfire.plugin.teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin,
           org.jivesoftware.util.ParamUtils,
           org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.Plugin,
           org.jivesoftware.util.*,
           java.util.*,
           java.util.HashMap,
           java.util.Map"
   errorPage="error.jsp"%>


<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt" prefix="fmt"%>

<%
    boolean save = request.getParameter("save") != null;    
    String pNameSpace = ParamUtils.getParameter(request, "pNameSpace");
    String pModule = ParamUtils.getParameter(request, "pModule");
    String pCreateUser = ParamUtils.getParameter(request, "pCreateUser");
    String pCreateUser_input = ParamUtils.getParameter(request, "pCreateUser_input");
    String pCreateUser_output = ParamUtils.getParameter(request, "pCreateUser_output");




  teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin plugin = (teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin) XMPPServer.getInstance().getPluginManager().getPlugin("teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin");


    Collection<Plugin> a = XMPPServer.getInstance().getPluginManager().getPlugins();

    out.write(Arrays.toString(a.toArray()));

    if(plugin == null) {

    out.println("Cant find plugin ..!!");
    return;
    }
```

And this is my directory structure:

```
/home/manoj/final/Openfire/src/plugins/teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin
|-- lib
|   |-- asm-3.1.jar
|   |-- commons-pool2-2.0.jar
|   |-- fluent-hc-4.3.2.jar
|   |-- httpclient-4.3.3.jar
|   |-- httpcore-4.3.2.jar
|   |-- jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
|   |-- jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
|   |-- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
|   |-- jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
|   |-- jedis-2.4.2.jar
|   |-- jersey-bundle-1.18.jar
|   |-- jersey-servlet-1.18.jar
|   |-- jettison-1.1.jar
|   `-- jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
|-- logo_large.gif
|-- logo_small.gif
|-- plugin.xml
|-- readme.html
`-- src
    |-- i18n
    |   `-- teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin_i18n.properties
    |-- java
    |   `-- de
    |       `-- meisterfuu
    |           `-- openfire
    |               `-- plugin
    |                   |-- teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin.java
    |                   `-- UserServiceHelper.java
    `-- web
        |-- images
        |   |-- error-16x16.gif
        |   `-- success-16x16.gif
        `-- teamFantasian_UserServicePlugin.jsp

10 directories, 24 files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use underscores for your plugin name.
Rename your Plugin to teamFantasianUserServicePlugin.

And get the Instance with:

```
XMPPServer.getInstance().getPluginManager().getPlugin("teamfantasianuserserviceplugin");
```

The plugin name should be lowercase.

Comment: Hey can you please show me any references, on how should i use a parent plugin.I cannot find any example code for it.

Comment: What do you mean with "parent plugin"?

Comment: I want to call methods of another plugin. For example i have userservice.jar, i want to use the methods of this plugin in my own plugin, instead of just copying the source code, that way if a new update for userservice.jar is found, then i don't have to refactor the code again.

Comment: parentPlugin -- the name of the parent plugin (given as "foo" for the "foo.jar" plugin). When a plugin has a parent plugin, the parent plugin's class loader will be used instead of creating a new class loader. This lets plugins work together more closely. A child plugin will not function without its parent present.http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html